# Decompressing a compressed image using PIL

Tags: python, python-2.7, compression, python-imaging-library, image-compression

I have compressed an image in python2.7 using PIL library like this:

picture.save("Compressed_"+file,"JPEG",quality=85)

Can I decompress it? 
I have searched so many sites, but couldn't find decompression related information.

I have to compress an image (should reduce file size) and decompress it back,what to do?

Comment: If you expect to get the full quality image back: the JPEG compression is not lossless.

Comment: If we are compressing png images, then how we will decompress it?

Comment: The compression is part of the file format, you just open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

JPEG use a [lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) method to do compression, which means there will be some data lost during compression. This data lost is irreversible.

You may try some lossless compressing image format, for example [PNG](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).

Comment: If we repalce the "jpeg" with "png" when compressing a png image, then also..how can we decompress that resulting image?

Comment: When `PIL` loads that image, it will "automatically" decode the image data.